# Spring hibernate relationship

Tags: angularjs, spring, hibernate

I am building an app with Spring Hibernate + ANgularJS
I have a model class JobDetail and another model JobReport. JobReport will contain one or more JobDetail references.
Here is the table JobDetail

```
JOB_ID 
NAME
CITY
JOB_NAME
```

Here is the table JobReport

```
REPORT_ID
NOTES
USER_NAME
JOB_ID
```

JobReport can contain one or more notes for one JobDetail

I tried the below by referring the docs in the internet
I defined the one-to-many relation in JobDetail as below

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="JOB_ID")
private int id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="jobnotes")
private List<JobReport> jobReport = new ArrayList<>();

public List<JobReport> getJobReport() {
    return jobReport;
}

public void setJobReport(List<JobReport> jobReport) {
    this.jobReport = jobReport;
}
```

I defined the many-to-one relation in JobReport as below,

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="JOB_ID")
private JobDetail jobnotes;

public JobDetail getJobnotes() {
    return jobnotes;
}

public void setJobnotes(JobDetail jobnotes) {
    this.jobnotes = jobnotes;
}
```

IS this correct or AM I missing something? 
In Angular how can I fetch the corresponding NOTES from JOBREPORT using the list JobDetail. I am using ng-repeat to fetch the details from JobDetail. I am able to get the list of items from JObDetail but not the corresponding notes from the JobReport list.

Any help please

Comment: Add `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` in `@OneToMany`

Comment: Thanks. I have added. Should I add the variable 'JOB_ID'  in the JOBREPORT table or it will be taken care automatically. If yes, how to populate the value for JOB_ID in the JOBREPORT table or ?

Comment: Yes, you have to add it. And one more thing: map your relationships in thegetters instead of in the field.

Comment: So you mean to say I have to add JOB_ID as a variable and have setters and getters inside JOBREPORT though it's a foreign key. Sure will do
I will also move the relationships to the getters.
The issue is the JOB_ID in the JOBREPORT table is always null. Any idea?

Comment: I added the JOB_ID in my JOBREPORT table and it throws an error
 @Column(name="JOB_ID")
 private String jobID;
 
 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name="JOB_ID")
 private JobDetail jobnotes;

org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.ctl.system.bean.JobReport column: JOB_ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked by the approach below. This is for someone who is looking for a solution

Here is JOBDETAIL class

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="jobnotes", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<JobReport> jobReport = new ArrayList<>();
```

Here is the JOBREPORT class

```
    @ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="JOB_ID", referencedColumnName = "JOB_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private JobDetail jobnotes;
```

I had the mapping on the fields

Comment: Setting a relationship itself to `EAGER` unnecessarily everywhere as seen in this case is a crazy solution which will only dump memory needlessly. It is only the matter of using fetch joins whenever needed.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

**JobDetail**

```
private int id;

private List<JobReport> jobReport = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy="jobnotes", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
public List<JobReport> getJobReport() {
    return jobReport;
}

public void setJobReport(List<JobReport> jobReport) {
    this.jobReport = jobReport;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="JOB_ID")
public int getId(){
    return id;
}
```

**JobReport**

```
private JobDetail jobnotes;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="JOB_ID", referencedColumnName = "JOB_ID")
public JobDetail getJobnotes() {
    return jobnotes;
}

public void setJobnotes(JobDetail jobnotes) {
    this.jobnotes = jobnotes;
}
```

JOB_REPORT table must have a column JOB_ID, but **you don't need to declare it in the entity model** if you don't want.

Note that I have changed annotations from fields to getters.

Comment: You will have some problems mixing fields and getters annotations ;)

Comment: For what reason? Intellij is capable to autogenerate mappings and it does this way.

Comment: I had some strange errors with Hibernate 5 metadata building when accidentally mixing fields and getters annotations. May be, using a field annotation for an id column is not a problem. But anyway I consider it as a bad technique :)

Comment: So what am I supposed to use.. Should I go with the FIELD annotation or at the getter

Comment: I tried moving the annotation as you have mentioned, it throws an error
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: JobDetail, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(jobReport)]

Comment: I use getter mapping with no errors for a long time. However, @v.ladynev has experimented errors in newer versions and I have read that Spring recommends field mappings, so... get your own conclusions.

Comment: @bigdestroyer Our team always use getters mappings too. :)

Comment: @CrazyMac This kind of error I had too with mixing (getters and fields) mappings.